# If $X,Y$ are two independent variables and $Z = f(X,Y)$ is a measurable function of the two, does it still hold that $E(X,Y|Z) = E(X|Z)E(Y|Z)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $X,Y$ are two independent variables, and $Z = f(X,Y)$ is a random variable that is a measurable function of the two, does it hold that $E(X,Y|Z) = E(X|Z)E(Y|Z)$?

I know this holds due to the tower property and proving my iterated expectations. However, does it hold when $Z$ is now a function of the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be i.i.d. Bernoulli with $p=1/2$, and let $Z=X+Y$.
Then $E[XY \mid Z=1] = 0$ while $E[X \mid Z=2] E[Y \mid Z=2]=\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$.